# Sentence case in wiki articles using AutoWikiBrowser

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to put the text of articles of a wiki in sentence case with [AutoWikiBrowser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:AutoWikiBrowser) (AWB) (an automated editor that handles regexes find and replace, but not all functions are available).

The problem is that wikicode uses many different tags to format text and there are also templates (inside double curly brakets), images (inside `[[File:image.png|Caption]]`) and categories (inside `[[Category:Category name]]`) that should stay untouched. Acronyms should stay in capitals too.

Section titles (inside two to five equal signs) should be put in sentence case, and words in links (inside double square brakets) should be treated as normal text.

I am having trouble because I'm not familiar with positive/negative lookahead/lookbehind, and I cannot find a way to make the regex simple, without having to write all the possible syntaxes.

Also, if it is possible for AWB to do several regexes in a row, it is not really feasible here, because for example I cannot make a regex to match words in the main text AND not inside templates (or I didn't find a way to do so).

Note that the case modifier `\L` doesn't work in AWB, but it can be replaced by `{{subst:lg:}}`, so don't mind about it and use `\L` in your examples, I'll adapt the code myself. Some tokens like `\h` doesn't work either, unfortunately I don't know what regex library AWB is using.

Here is an example of an article I want to edit, I want to match only the `Yes`:

```
No Yes no Yes. No, Yes.
== No Yes no ==
==== No Yes ====
[[No Yes]] Yes Yes no no no.
No no [[NO Yes]].
'''[[No Yes]]'''
''[[No Yes]]'' no Yes ''[[Yes Yes]]'' no ''Yes no''.
{{No:No|No No}}
* No Yes.
* '''No Yes'''.
* [[No Yes]].
* '''[[No Yes]]'''.
# No Yes.
#** No Yes.
#: No Yes.
No no no [[File:No.png|No No]] Yes [[Yes Yes]].
[[Category:No No]]
```

For example, I tried to use this regex:
Find: `(?<!\n|\. |\[\[Category:|\[\[File:)(?<!\{\||\{\{|^\[\[|<!--|^== |^=== |^==== |^===== |^''|^''')(\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b)(?![\w\s]*[\}|}]|[\w\s]*-->)`
Replace: \L$1

But it seems overly complicated and it's not working like I'd like too.

Sorry if this seems complicated, but I'm trying for two days now and I seem to be running in circles...

**[EDIT]**

The question has been answered blow, but I'd like to add a request: can this regex work only outisde of multiline comments (inside `<!--` / `-->` tags) and tables (inside `{|` / `|}` tags)?

It would be even better if sentence case could be put into table cells (delimited by pipes and exclamation points), that may include links and/or italic/bold?

Here's a how it would look like:

```
No Yes

<!-- No No No
No No
No
-->

{| class="wikitable"
|+ No Yes
|-
! '''No Yes''' !! '''No''' !! '''[[No Yes]]'''
|-
| ''No Yes'' || ''[[No Yes Yes]]'' || ''No Yes''
|-
| No Yes || No Yes || [[No Yes Yes]]
|}
```

Comment: Check [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/W3rAPO/1), `(?!^)(?<!\. |\[\[(?:Category|File):[^\]\[]*)(?<!\{\||\{\{|^(?:(?:\*\s*)?'?''|\*\s*)?\[\[|<!--|^=+\s*|^#(?::|\*+)?\s*|^\*\s*(?:''')?)\b([A-Z][a-z]*)\b(?![^{}]*}}|[\w\s]*-->)(?<!\[\[(?:Category|File)(?=:[^\]\[]*]]))`. It is using variable-width lookbehind though.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor, it seems to work fine on my example text, I am going to test in on the wiki.
It teaches me to use non capturing groups (`(?:)`) inside lookahead/behind groups, that is a method I was looking for without being able to find it in the documentations.
I even think that I'll be able to adapt your regex to my needs now.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew : by the way, where did you find that AWB is using ECMAScript ?
This can help me a lot when making regexes with regex101.com, this always been an issue for me.

Comment: I do not know if it uses ECMAScript or not. You mentioned `\h` is not supported, but lookarounds are. It could be Python, JS, or .NET then, and the latter two support variable width lookbehinds. Do you think I should post the regex as an answer? Is it working as it should?

Comment: After some research, I think it is written in .NET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:AutoWikiBrowser/Technical .The documentation is a bit confusing on Wikipedia, as documentation external sites about Perl and Python are mentioned.
I'm not tech savy enough to know better about this unfortunately...

Comment: I didn't tested it yet on AWB, I am making little changes about lists that can have other syntaxes than the ones I put in my example.

Comment: At first sight it seems to work well, I have to add some rules for unwanted matches inside tables (I didn't mention them in my example) and it should be fine.
The thing is I have a preview of the code of the wiki article before saving it, and I can choose where to apply the regex rules or not. The goal is to have as few false positives as possible to save time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the regex flavor used in AWB turns out to be .NET, you can use a regex with variable-width lookbehind patterns:

```cs
(?m)(?!^)(?<!\.\s+|\[\[(?:Category|File):[^\]\[]*)(?<!\{\||\{\{|^(?:(?:\*\s*)?'?''|\*\s*)?\[\[|<!--|^=+\s*|^#(?::|\*+)?\s*|^\*\s*(?:''')?)\b([A-Z][a-z]*)\b(?![^{}]*}}|[\w\s]*-->)(?<!\[\[(?:Category|File)(?=:[^\]\[]*]]))
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f!%5e%29%28%3f%3c!%5c.%5cs%2b%7c%5c%5b%5c%5b%28%3f%3aCategory%7cFile%29%3a%5b%5e%5c%5d%5c%5b%5d*%29%28%3f%3c!%5c%7b%5c%7c%7c%5c%7b%5c%7b%7c%5e%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3a%5c*%5cs*%29%3f%27%3f%27%27%7c%5c*%5cs*%29%3f%5c%5b%5c%5b%7c%3c!--%7c%5e%3d%2b%5cs*%7c%5e%23%28%3f%3a%3a%7c%5c*%2b%29%3f%5cs*%7c%5e%5c*%5cs*%28%3f%3a%27%27%27%29%3f%29%5cb%28%5bA-Z%5d%5ba-z%5d*%29%5cb%28%3f!%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%7d%7d%7c%5b%5cw%5cs%5d*--%3e%29%28%3f%3c!%5c%5b%5c%5b%28%3f%3aCategory%7cFile%29%28%3f%3d%3a%5b%5e%5c%5d%5c%5b%5d*%5d%5d%29%29&i=No+Yes+no+Yes.+No%2c+Yes.%0d%0a%3d%3d+No+Yes+no+%3d%3d%0d%0a%3d%3d%3d%3d+No+Yes+%3d%3d%3d%3d%0d%0a%5b%5bNo+Yes%5d%5d+Yes+Yes+no+no+no.%0d%0aNo+no+%5b%5bNO+Yes%5d%5d.%0d%0a%27%27%27%5b%5bNo+Yes%5d%5d%27%27%27%0d%0a%27%27%5b%5bNo+Yes%5d%5d%27%27+no+Yes+%27%27%5b%5bYes+Yes%5d%5d%27%27+no+%27%27Yes+no%27%27.%0d%0a%7b%7bNo%3aNo%7cNo+No%7d%7d%0d%0a*+No+Yes.%0d%0a*+%27%27%27No+Yes%27%27%27.%0d%0a*+%5b%5bNo+Yes%5d%5d.%0d%0a*+%27%27%27%5b%5bNo+Yes%5d%5d%27%27%27.%0d%0a%23+No+Yes.%0d%0a%23**+No+Yes.%0d%0a%23%3a+No+Yes.%0d%0aNo+no+no+%5b%5bFile%3aNo.png%7cNo+No%5d%5d+Yes+%5b%5bYes+Yes%5d%5d.%0d%0a%5b%5bCategory%3aNo+No%5d%5d&o=m). *Details*:

- `(?m)` - multiline mode on
- `(?!^)` - not at the start of a line
- `(?<!\.\s+|\[\[(?:Category|File):[^\]\[]*)` - immediately before, there should be no `.` and one or more whitespaces, or `[[` followed with `Category` or `File` and then `:` and then zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `(?<!\{\||\{\{|^(?:(?:\*\s*)?'?''|\*\s*)?\[\[|<!--|^=+\s*|^#(?::|\*+)?\s*|^\*\s*(?:''')?)` - negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately before, there are patterns like

  - `\{\||` - `{|` string, or
  - `\{\{|` - `{{` string, or
  - `^(?:(?:\*\s*)?'?''|\*\s*)?\[\[|` - an optional sequence of an optional sequence of `*` and zero ro more spaces followed with an optional `'` char and then `''` or a `*` char followed with zero or more whitespaces, and then `[[`, or
  - `<!--|^=+\s*|`
  - `^#(?::|\*+)?\s*|`
  - `^\*\s*(?:''')?`
- `\b` - word boundary
- `([A-Z][a-z]*)` - an uppercase letter followed with zero or more lowercase letters (in .NET, you can also use `\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*` to match any Unicode letters)
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?![^{}]*}}|[\w\s]*-->)` - a negative lookahead: no match allowed if there are zero or more chars other than `{` and `}` and then `}}` or any zero or more word/whitespace chars and then `-->`
- `(?<!\[\[(?:Category|File)(?=:[^\]\[]*]]))` - fail the match if, immediately before, there is `[[`, `Category` or `File` and right after, there are zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then `]]`.

Comment: Can you please look in the first post, I'd like to add a request for exluding matches in comments and tables, as I can't find a way to do so.

Comment: @oli_vi_er See ``(?!^)(?<!\.\s+| \|\| (?:''|\[\[)?|(?m:^\| (?:'')?|^\|\+\s*)|! '''(?:\[\[)?| ''\[\[|\[\[(?:Category|File):[^\]\[]*)(?<!\{\||\{\{|^(?:(?:\*\s*)?'?''|\*\s*)?\[\[|<!--|^=+\s*|^#(?::|\*+)?\s*|^\*\s*(?:''')?)\b([A-Z][a-z]*)\b(?![^{}]*}}|[\w\s]*-->)(?<!\[\[(?:Category|File)(?=:[^\]\[]*]]))``

Comment: Thank you!
I guess that the m is a typo in (?m:^\| (?:'')?|^\|\+\s*), without it it seems to work as intended.
I really wish that I could have your abilities in making regexes, it often takes me hours of trial and error, wihtout being sure to make something usable...

Comment: Actually, the `m` doesn't seem to be a problem for AWB (it is one for regex101 with ECMAScript library).

Comment: Then please do not use regex101, it is not .NET regex compatible.

Comment: Your regex still matches for words between exclamation marks inside tables, e.g.
`{| {{STDT| sortable c_08 text-left}}`
`! Options !! Description !! Value Options`

Comment: Actually, I just have to add `!\s*` in the first negative lookbehind to solve it.
In addition, it doesn't matches first words of sentences following a sentence ending with an exlamation mark (even it they are very rare on wikis)

Comment: What online regex tester would be good for .NET then?
I found http://regexstorm.net/tester on Google, but are there are better ones?

Comment: There is no better than that one, but you may try regexhero.net